# Retaining Dagger 2 Subcomponent

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

Is it possible to retain a Dagger 2 subcomponent for an activity through a configuration change?
It seems like the only two possible solutions are:

- to use a retained Fragment, or
- to save the state of the objects in the subcomponent and restore it using the savedInstanceState `Bundle`.

Both seem like messy solutions - has anyone solved this problem with a cleaner solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question sounds like something that you should not try to do.

A component that is created and dependent on the activity will likely have a reference to the activity. Retaining that component sounds like a primary cause for memory leaks.

When your configuration changes, the activity is destroyed and everything associated with it *should also be destroyed.*

So what you mentioned—saving the state in the bundle `onSaveInstanceState` and recreating it again—sounds like the cleanest solution to me.

Comment: After doing some reading and having a discussion with another Android developer, we came to the same conclusion that it was way messier to think about retaining components. We ended up settling on the second and actually found a way to handle it fairly cleanly using Gson to serialize/deserialize the state of our view models. Always great to have additional input though, especially affirmation, thanks!